# Clipboardy Can't resolve dependency modules

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to use clipboardy as a dependency of my angular project.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/clipboardy/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\repositories\ui\ui\node_modules\clipboardy\node_modules\cross-spawn' 
ERROR in ./node_modules/clipboardy/node_modules/execa/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\repositories\ui\ui\node_modules\clipboardy\node_modules\execa' 
ERROR in ./node_modules/clipboardy/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/util/readShebang.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\repositories\ui\ui\node_modules\clipboardy\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\util' 
ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\repositories\ui\ui\node_modules\isexe' 
ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/windows.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\repositories\ui\ui\node_modules\isexe' 
ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/mode.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\repositories\ui\ui\node_modules\isexe' 
ERROR in ./node_modules/clipboardy/node_modules/get-stream/buffer-stream.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\repositories\ui\ui\node_modules\clipboardy\node_modules\get-stream'
```

When I add it as a development dependency and I add some usage for it, the angular application doesn't start with several errors

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as clipboardy from 'clipboardy';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'dummy';
  onInit(){
     clipboardy.read();
  }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This is server-side only code. You need: https://github.com/sindresorhus/copy-text-to-clipboard

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks.